# NSDateComponentsFormatter's method stringFromDate:ToDate: is returning a different value every second

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdatecomponentsformatter

I am trying to get the number of days between today's date and a future date.
I call the following every second:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setYear:2025];
[components setMonth:1];
[components setDay:1];

NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *futureDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:components];

NSDateComponentsFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = NSDateComponentsFormatterZeroFormattingBehaviorNone;
formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitDay;
formatter.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyleAbbreviated;
NSString *remainingDaysAsString = [formatter stringFromDate:currentDate toDate:futureDate];
```

I print the variable remainingDaysAsString every second and it is always different by a day.

```
3,551d
3,551d
3,550d
3,550d
3,551d
3,550d
3,551d
```

Has anyone experienced something similar? Does this seem like a bug with the class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is strange and looks like a bug. The result of `NSDateComponentsFormatter` are correct (in my test) if you specify
all units down to seconds:

```
formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitDay + NSCalendarUnitHour + NSCalendarUnitMinute  + NSCalendarUnitSecond;
```

A simpler and reliable method to get the number of days between two dates is

```
NSDateComponents *comp = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                      fromDate:currentDate
                                                        toDate:futureDate
                                                       options:0];
NSInteger days = comp.day;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Martin. Your simpler method works like a charm. Did it work correctly when you just used NSCalendarUnitDay however?

Comment: @Patrick: No, I could reproduce your problem with NSCalendarUnitDay. In fact the lowest unit was sometimes wrong if seconds are not included, e.g. with NSCalendarUnitDay + NSCalendarUnitHour. Perhaps some rounding error, I don't know.

Comment: I may file a radar as this definitely seems like strange behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem:

```swift
let fmt1 = NSDateComponentsFormatter()

fmt1.allowedUnits = .CalendarUnitYear |
    .CalendarUnitMonth |
    .CalendarUnitDay

let dc1 = NSDateComponents()
dc1.month = 1
dc1.day = 15

// This occasionally outputs "1 month, 14 days" instead of
// "1 month, 15 days" when the formatter is constrained to
// years, months and days. If formatter is allowed to use
// all units, the output is "1 month, 14 days, 23 hours,
// 59 minutes, 59 seconds".
fmt1.stringFromDateComponents(dc1)
```

This can be fixed by specifying a positive amount of seconds and combining it with
restricting allowed units and/or setting `maximumUnitCount` formatter parameter to a fixed value:

```swift
let fmt2 = NSDateComponentsFormatter()

fmt2.allowedUnits = .CalendarUnitYear |
    .CalendarUnitMonth |
    .CalendarUnitDay

fmt2.maximumUnitCount = 2
fmt2.collapsesLargestUnit = true

let dc2 = NSDateComponents()
dc2.month = 1
dc2.day = 15
dc2.second = 10

// This always outputs "1 month, 15 days"
fmt2.stringFromDateComponents(dc2)
```

So, in your case, just assign some positive amount of seconds to `NSDateComponents`:

```
[components setYear:2025];
[components setMonth:1];
[components setDay:1];
[components setSecond:10];
```

This will prevent rounding errors.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about the issue you are describing, just want you to know an alternative method.

```
NSDate * date1; 
NSDate * date2;
//assuming both vars contain a date
NSTimeInterval duration = [date2 timeIntervalSince1970] - [date1 timeIntervalSince1970];
NSLog("@days between %@ and %@: %f", date1, date2, duration / (24 * 60 * 60));
```

Comment: A day does not always have 86400 seconds. When the clock is adjusted for daylight saving time, a day can have 23 or 25 hours.

Comment: timeIntervalSince1970 takes it into account

Comment: No, it doesn't. In Germany, summer time started this year on March 29, the clocks were moved forward by one hour at 2 am. If I compute the difference between 29.03.2015 and 30.03.2015 (midnight) using your method, I get a difference of 82800 seconds or 0.958333 days.

Comment: This method also seems to work perfectly like Martin's. Upvotes for both but I'm just going to wait and see if anyone knows the reason why NSDateComponentsFormatter isn't working as it should.


Edit: Martin seems to raise a point however about things like daylight savings.

Comment: I can assure you, it does. I recently faced the problem when russian day saving was cancelled on november 2014 and iOS 7 behaved wrong - it was producing minus one hour dates but iOS 8 did produce correct dates with the same code and timestamp values.

Comment: ah, I see where is our misunderstanding. when you add 82800 to some timestamp there is no guarantee the result will be correct. but when iOS generates two days with timeIntervalSince1970 you may be sure the date difference will be correct.

Comment: There must be some misunderstanding, but I still don't get your point. NSDate represents an absolute point in time, represented internally as number of seconds since Jan 1, 2001 GMT. NSDate does not know anything about time zones, daylight saving times or calendars. If you compute the no of seconds between two midnights then you can get 23*3600, 24*3600 or 25*3600 seconds. To compute the number of *calendar days* you'll have to use NSCalendar. (Of course if iOS has a wrong calendar then this might fail as well.)

Comment: NSDate does know about time zones, timeIntervalSince1970 is not just simple arithmetic operation, there is an intelligent algorithm calculating a number of seconds.

Comment: @heximal: Nonsense. NSDate knows nothing. It doesn't calculate anything. Calendars do the calculating. NSDate knows time differences in seconds. It has no ideas how many days. It has no idea how many years.